# Prove $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = - \infty$ where $ \lim_{x\to a }g(x) = c$, and $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 0$ through negative values of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'm not sure how to stitch this proof together.

## Question

If $a \in \mathbb{R}$ , and if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 0$, and $\lim_{x \to a}
g(x) = c$ , where $c \neq 0$, then

If $c > 0$ , and if $f(x) \to 0$ through negative values of $f(x)$

Prove:

$$  
\lim_{x \to a} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = - \infty
$$

## Numerator

If $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 0$, then for any negative number $K$, there exists
$\delta_1$, such that for $0 < |x - a| < \delta_1$, $\frac{1}{f(x)} < K$

## Denominator

If $\lim_{x \to a } g(x) = c$, then given $\epsilon > 0$ , there exists
$\delta_2 > 0$ such that for $0 < |x- a| < \delta_2$, $|g(x) - c| < \epsilon$.
Using the triangle inequality $|g(x) - |c| \leq |g(x) - c| < \epsilon $ , so
$g(x) < \epsilon + c$ , (as $c > 0$ and $g(x) > 0$ ).

Then, for $0 < |x - a| < \min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$, $g(x) \cdot \frac{1}{f(x)} <
(\epsilon + c) \cdot K$.

## Putting these together

What am I meant to do from here though?

I want to show that $(\epsilon + c) \cdot K \to - \infty$. Here, $c$ is a fixed
value and (I think) I can also fix $\epsilon$. In which case if $\epsilon + c =
p$ then $p \cdot K \to -\infty$ as $K$ is a negative number that can be taken as
small as we please.

Given that $ \lim_{x \to a}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)} < p \cdot K$, this would mean that
$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = - \infty$

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that for all $M<0$, there is a $\delta>0$ s.t. $$|x-a|<\delta\implies \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}<M.$$

By the fact that $g(x)\to c>0$, there is $\delta_1>0$ s.t. $$|x-a|<\delta_1\implies 0<g(x)<\frac{3c}{2}.$$

Let $M<0$. By the fact that $f(x)\to 0^-$, there is $\delta_2>0$ s.t. $$|x-a|<\delta_2\implies \frac{3c}{2M}<f(x)<0.$$
Let $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}.$
Then $$|x-a|<\delta\implies \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}<\frac{3c}{2}\cdot \frac{2M}{3c}=M.$$

The claim follow.

Comment: Thank you. In the step $\frac{3c}{2M} < f(x)$, I understand that $1/M < f(x) < 0$ here, but I guess it's not so intuitive that I can multiply $1/M$ by any constant and still have this property (rather than having to have some kind of $M_1, M_2$ used throughout the proof in the same way $\delta_i$ is). So we don't need to represent these $M$'s as different?

Comment: @baxx: By definition, since $f(x)\to 0$, then $$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0: \forall x\in \mathbb R, |x-a|<\delta\implies |f(x)|<\varepsilon.$$ So here, I just took $\varepsilon=\frac{3c}{2M}$. Notice that if you take $\delta$ s.t. $1/M<f(x)<0$, at the end, you'll get $\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}<\frac{3c}{2}M$ what also prove the claim. I just wanted to have $M$ and not $\frac{3c}{2}M$, but it's not really important.

Comment: OK - what's written is explicit enough then?

Comment: yes, it is :-).

Comment: OK thanks... I think I need to appreciate more how this was  / can be chosen in such a manner

Answer (score 1):

You might be making it harder on yourself by thinking about functions. Just think about sequences of real numbers instead.

**Hint**: Let $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$ be sequences such that $$a_n\rightarrow c>0 \qquad b_n < 0 \qquad b_n \rightarrow 0.$$ Now try to show that for each $M>0$, we can find $n$ large enough such that $a_n/b_n < -M$.

Comment: thanks for an alternative way to view it, sequences haven't been introduced at this point though, so (i think) the approach taken is the "correct" one (I don't mean to say that your approach isn't better in general of course)

Comment: It is unfortunate that you are being introduced to limits of functions before limits of sequences, in my opinion.

Comment: Fair, yeah limits and continuity are introduced leading to differentiation. Following that anti derivatives and integration *then* sequences and series. (The text is leitholds calculus fwiw).

Comment: That's actually a pretty standard topic order in the United States, often with a semester break between integration and sequences (or even in the middle of integration), to allow students whose majors only require derivatives and integrals to quit.  (So Calculus 1 is limits, derivatives, and integrals; Calculus 2 is more integrals maybe, sequences, series, maybe something with vectors; Calculus 3 is vectors and matrices and/or multivariable calculus.)  This is pragmatic in meeting the requirements of various engineering majors but logically backwards from a pure-math perspective.